# Woocommerce rest api showing square brackets[]" only

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

MY woocommerce website with **REST API** with **PUT** and **GET** requests are working fine even on cloudflare(which few users complained about not working with cloudflare).

But only with **PUT** (I said GET is also working I'll come to that)
So my actual problem after troubleshooting I found was GET is working if i remove categories or sales from the request URL

here's my Code

**1.with sale=true and categories**

`example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?page=1&on_sale=true&consumer_key=ck_b5f10.....&consumer_secret=cs_232690...&category=125`

output

```
id": 3268,
        "name": "Product",
        "slug": "product-3",
        "permalink": "https://...
```

**2.without categories with sale =false**

```
example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?page=1&on_sale=false&consumer_key=ck_b5f10.....&consumer_secret=cs_232690...
```

output

```
id": 3268,
        "name": "Product",
        "slug": "product-3",
        "permalink": "https://...
```

**3.with sale=false and categories**

```
example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?page=1&on_sale=false&consumer_key=ck_b5f10.....&consumer_secret=cs_232690...&category=125
```

output

```
[]
```

With **PUT** everything works fine My problem here is my app is making #3 requests only

Comment: Seems to be a valid response (just no results), is there any products in the category with id 125 that are not on sale ?

Comment: @JasperB As I said it is working with sale=true. also working with PUT even if sale =false However category 125 do have products. are there any configuration setup for rest api on backend? thanks for the reply.
Also are [] default for some error?

Comment: no it's not an error, [] ist the 200 response for no getting no results. read the docs, pls.

Comment: [jasie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/917492/jasie) thanks for the reply problem solved my app was sending the wrong requests. ref to the answer i gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved my site has products that have discount(selling and actual price)But app only requesting the ones that doesn't have any discounts.

For the kinds of problems to solve quickly first try with different server then go through requests URL properly.